# Plotting a Taylor Series of two-variable trigonometric function

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

I am pretty sure I have made an obvious mistake. I want to plot a Taylor polynomial of a degree 4 around the point (0, 0). So I have defined a function

```
f[x_, y_] := Cos[x + y]
```

Then I write a Taylor series up to 4th degree

```
Series[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]
```

I can plot the function `f`, but when I try to plot series I get errors. I believe it is because. when computing the series, along from the terms I will also get a remainder, which can not be plotted.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Normal` and `Evaluate`,e.g.:

```
t[n_] := Plot3D[
  Evaluate[Series[Cos[x + y], {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}] // Normal], {x, 0,
    2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

An animation of truncated series: 1 to 20:

[image]